# Installing and using Orfeo Toolbox (OTB) through Python

Tags: python, orfeo-toolbox, jupyter-notebook, otb-applications

Using Python v.3.6.8 through Jupyter notebook (in Windows 10), how can I set and use OTB (v.7.3.0)?

I followed the steps described in the official cookbook and other tutorials, however, the result is:

```
No module named 'otbApplication'
```

If you have already solved this problem, can you describe the various steps (starting from scratch)?

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows 10 system, I think you can use Anaconda to build a python3.7 virtual environment, and use otbenv.bat to bind in this environment, open Jupyter Notebook to import otbApplication.
E.g:
Open the anaconda prompt window of anaconda3,enter as follows:

```
(base) conda create -n py3.7 python==3.7
(base) conda activate py3.7
(py3.7) conda install numpy
(py3.7) conda install ipykernel
(py3.7) conda deactivate
(base) conda install nb_conda_kernels

(base) conda activate py3.7
(py3.7) C:\OTB-8.0.1-Win64\otbenv.bat
(py3.7) python
>>> import os
>>> import otbApplication as otb
```

Below is my specific solution,but written in Chinese:

[Bind OTB to python3 under Windows system]

> https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_44510686/article/details/126215778